# Looping through (and displaying) multiple table rows from SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Having trouble looping through multiple rows in a SQL table and getting the info to display correctly. The closest I have got is the following:

```
<table border="1" cellpadding="10">
<th>Stock</th><th>Price</th><th>Shares</th><th>Value</th><th>Sell Stock</th>
<?php
$transactions = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM transactions WHERE email='$email'");
while ($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($transactions)) {
    foreach($rows as $row) {
        $symbol = $row["symbol"];
        $price = $row["price"];
        $shares = $row["shares"];
        $value = $price * $shares;
?>
        <form name="sellStock" action="sell.php" method="get">
        <tr>
            <td><input name="symbol" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $symbol ?>"><?php echo $symbol ?></td>
            <td><input name="price" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $price ?>"><?php echo $price ?></td>
            <td><input name="shares" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $shares ?>"><?php echo $shares ?></td>
            <td><input name="value" type="hidden" value="<?php $value ?>" /><?php $value ?></td>
            <td><input name="sell" type="submit" value="Sell"></td>
        </tr>
<?php
    }
}
?>
</table>
```

The while/foreach loop goes on to display the info from the rows into a HTML table, but it displays the first character from every column as opposed to all the characters from the columns I echo to be displayed (symbol, price, and shares). Any ideas?

Comment: Do you mean you do (e.g.) `echo $symbol;` and it only shows the first character? We might need to see the code you wrote to print the HTML table - trimmed down that still reproduces the problem if possible.

Comment: Can you show the code where it's actually echoing into the table?

Comment: Yes, your code looks fine. The problem must lie in subsequent code that affects `$symbol` etc. or their output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<table border="1" cellpadding="10">

<th>Stock</th><th>Price</th><th>Shares</th><th>Value</th><th>Sell Stock</th>
<?php
$transactions = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM transactions WHERE email='$email'");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($transactions)) {
        $symbol = $row["symbol"];
        $price = $row["price"];
        $shares = $row["shares"];
        $value = $price * $shares;
?>
        <form name="sellStock" action="sell.php" method="get">
        <tr>
            <td><input name="symbol" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $symbol ?>"><?php echo $symbol ?></td>
            <td><input name="price" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $price ?>"><?php echo $price ?></td>
            <td><input name="shares" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $shares ?>"><?php echo $shares ?></td>
            <td><input name="value" type="hidden" value="<?php $value ?>" /><?php $value ?></td>
            <td><input name="sell" type="submit" value="Sell"></td>
        </tr>
<?php
}
?>
</table>
```

You just had one loop too many. The `while` loop continues until `!$row`, with one row per execution, so you don't want the `foreach` loop you had.